# How to generate a serial number to series of constant change in Sql Server rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need date difference of first TSL Sender with Subsequent Vendor and next first TSL to next subsequent sender as Vendor

[image]

Desired output

[image]

Comment: what is that value `1.83` ?

Comment: that is the difference of date for id 159-156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a grouping to the rows by counting the number of `'Vendor'` values on or after each row.  Then each grouping ends with `'Vendor'` and you can use window functions within that group:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sender = 'vendor'
             then datediff(second,
                           min(date) over (partition by grp),
                           max(date) over (partition by grp)
                          ) / (24 * 60 * 60.0)
        end) as diff
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when sender = 'Vendor' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

so you want the difference of days when TSL changes to Vendor. You can use the analytical function as follows:

```
select t.*,
       case when sender = 'Vendor' 
            then DATEDIFF(hour, date, first_value(date) over (partition by rn - rn_s order by date) ) / 24.0 end as diff
  from
(select t.*,
       row_number() over (order by date) as rn,
       row_number() over (partition by sender order by date) as rn_s
  from yout_table t) t
```